# How to prevent usage of multi-dex in android gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Following is my gradle file. I am getting a MultiDexException. I don’t want to enable multidex because my app is not that complicated. So I am convinced that I must be doing something wrong. Will someone please look at my gradle file and point to what I can do to avoid the problem?

ERROR:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

GRADLE:

```
buildscript {
         repositories {     
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }     
    }          
    dependencies {     
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
         }
     }
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'     
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'          
repositories {
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }     
}               
android {
         compileSdkVersion 23     
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
              defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.company.app.android"     
        minSdkVersion 14     
        targetSdkVersion 23
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
         }     
    buildTypes {
             release {     
            minifyEnabled false     
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
         }
               }
          dependencies {
         compile project(path: ':cloud', configuration: 'android-endpoints')     
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
             transitive = true;
         }
              compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
         compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
         compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
         compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
     }
```

Comment: This is an app-engine connected project. I don't suppose the app-engine gradle would affect the android gradle.

Answer (score 5):

> I don’t want to enable multidex because my app is not that complicated

You have direct dependencies on 11 artifacts. You have indirect dependencies upon others (e.g., `play-services-location` pulls in `play-services-maps`), plus anything that might get set up as dependencies courtesy of your Fabric plugin.

In short, your app is rather complicated. It just so happens that *you* did not write much of that complexity.

> what I can do to avoid the problem?

Use fewer/smaller dependencies.

You already are using fine-grained Play Services SDK dependencies, otherwise you would have hit the DEX limit quite some time ago.

You might consider using one of the available method-count tools, like [this Gradle plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin), to get a better idea of which libraries are contributing to your cost.

Comment: but this library only shows us the limit what to resolve above problem? even i also face the same what to do if we have to include too much libraries and still dont want to enable multidex?

Comment: @HBdroid: You do not have much of a choice. ProGuard can help some, if you enable it for debug builds. Eventually, you either need to use fewer libraries, use multidex, split your app into multiple apps (each of which needing a subset of the libraries), or abandon the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know how to disable MultiDex? I created a new empty android application project, built it and checked the resulting APK file with APK Analyzer. In the APK file, there is always classes2.dex file along with classes.dex. Of course the reference count is very very low, and also tried extending Activity class instead of the default AppCompatActivity in order to reduce dependencies, but the result was the same. Moreover, when I decompiled those dex files, I couldn't find any MainActivity.class while it's working as expected on my device.

Comment: I did these tests several times because my original application has the same problem. MultiDex files with low reference count. And also can't find my class files in the dex files even though I never applied ProGuard.. I don't know what's happening here. Why in the world default MultiDex.. Any hint for me, please?

Comment: @Jenix: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain these steps and provide screenshots showing what you are seeing.

Comment: I really want to but I thought this kind of questions is not acceptable here anymore since it's not programming question with specific code. Is it really okay to ask?

Comment: @Jenix: The "specific code" is the new empty project. If you show your empty project contents (notably both `build.gradle` files) and the output of the build process (screenshots showing your DEX files), that should qualify for Stack Overflow, IMHO.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to obfuscate and remove unused class. But remember to config it carefully if you don't want your app to be "cut-off" so much. Proguard can be very aggressive.